# implementation of a location based application

Tags: android, gps

I have a idea of a project but i cant understand how to start and where to start.
The idea is that there are some users of my app.The basic info like name,phone number,blood group are stored in online in my app.So when a user needs blood suppose A+ group then he message to the online where the info is stored.message will be delivered to the users who have the same blood group which the sender is looking for and the user should be same location where the sender is located using gps.

where and how can i store the information of the users for response??

What i have to do to implement that?
Can anyone give me any suggestion?

Comment: Android has a very good support for location based services (by using the LocationManager class). check out this link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

Comment: While sending the request to the web service send the users present latitude and longitude also. and see if that lat/lon matches or is close with any other donors lat/lon..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please be more specific that are you planning to develop application which supports almost all mobile platforms? If you are planning like that, better to go with `Phonegap`(now, `Cordova`) which supports `GPS` location retrieval, calling web services using `Ajax`. If you are planning for specific mobile platform, your application's requirements are supported by all the Mobile OS SDKs.

Comment: I want to build the app into android mobile.So how can i start? how can i store the information of users and how can i receive message and send message according the info and location ?

Comment: Okay. First Create a screen with Login information. When the user clicks Login, store the user info locally in Sqlite database. Next, validate the user login info with the server using webservice. If the user is valid, get the GPS Location using `LocationManager` of the user and other information. Call a webservice and check the users who are in the same location. Send the data to those users either through email/SMS.....

Comment: I cant get how can i make that server and how can i send and response message from server ?? Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: Please check this http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/consuming-json-services-android-apps for how to call a webservice and handling JSON and this http://java.dzone.com/articles/how-create-web-service-using for video tutorial on how to create a webservice in java. Please google for more information. You can easily find out.

Answer (score 0):

There can be several ways. Just sharing my ideas:

1. when the data is entered or updated, send to the server
2. Whenever a location is changed sends the updated location to the server. (check [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) to know how to update the location changes
3. Now the server knows all the info with the updated location.
4. When a user requests for blood, sends the request to server. In server match the requirements and closest locations. Send message to those targeted users using Google cloud messaging.

Comment: I dont understand how can i make that server and how can i send and response message from server ??

Comment: oopss.. I just wrote the concept. .. now you need to learn ..1. how to make a server.... 2. how to make android ap...3. network strategies ..4. gcm

Comment: I know this but not clear about the server. I didn't work with this before that's why i have no idea about this.

Comment: then please google how to create a basic server :s